# rolling geometric mean in data.table vs dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I'm trying to calculate geometric mean and 90th percentile for rolling 90 day windows for each group ID. It works in data.table but not in dplyr which I'm more comfortable with. DT_new is what the output should look like. Also tibbletime, zoo-rollapply and tbrf were all unsuccessful hence manual rolling.

1) How can I do this in dplyr?

2) In data.table how can I modify the code so that it adds both the new geometric mean and quantile columns in one statement?

3) In data.table how can I also add a column called "Group" for each 90 day window?

```
 geo_mean <- function(data) {
 log_data <- log(data)
 gm <- exp(mean(log_data[is.finite(log_data)]))
 return(gm)
 }
  ###sample data#
 Value=c(50,900,25,25,125,50,25,25,2000,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,325,25,300,475,25)
Date = as.Date(c("2015-02-23","2015-04-20","2015-06-17",
    "2015-08-20","2015-10-05","2015-12-22",
    "2016-01-19","2016-03-29","2016-05-03",
    "2016-07-21","2016-09-08","2016-11-07",
    "2017-02-27","2017-04-19","2017-06-29",
    "2017-08-24","2017-10-23","2017-12-28",
    "2018-01-16","2018-03-14","2018-05-29",
    "2018-07-24"))
ID = c(rep("A", 11), rep("B", 11))
df=data.frame(Value,Date,ID) 
require(data.table) 
DT=setDT(df) #####Works with data.table but I have to run it twice#######
  DTnew= DT[, Rollquantile:= { 
d <- DT$Date- Date
quantile(DT$Value[ID == DT$ID & d <= 0 & d >= -90],0.90)
},by = list(Date,ID)]
DT_new= DTnew[, Rollgeomean:= { 
d <- DT$Date- Date
 geo_mean(DT$Value[ID == DT$ID & d <= 0 & d >= -90])
},by = list(Date,ID)]

############ won't work in dplyr########
df_new=df %>% group_by(ID,Date) %>% mutate(d = df$Date- Date, 
Geomean=geo_mean(df$Value[ID == df$ID & d <= 0 & d >= -90]),
Quantile= quantile(df$Value[ID == df$ID & d <= 0 & d >= -90],0.90))

##failed attempt to add "Group"########
paste0("Group_", 1 + c(0, cumsum((c(TRUE, lag(Date.Time) > 90)))))
```

Comment: Re 2, `c("col1", "col2") := {...; list(val1, val2)}` should work. Re 3, looks like `d` has length nrow(DT) for each group, so it's not clear what you intend to assign.

Comment: I was thinking it would be useful to know how many sample days were included for each calculation. Maybe `d`is not that. @Frank

Comment: That did work. :  `DT_new3= DTnew[, c("col1","col2"):= { 
  d <- DT$Date- Date  val1=geo_mean(DT$Value[ID == DT$ID & d <= 0 & d >= -90])
  val2=quantile(DT$Value[ID == DT$ID & d <= 0 & d >= -90],0.90);list(val1, val2)
  },by = list(Date,ID)]`